# geeqie: copy path to clipboard does nothing

Tags: clipboard, application

```
geeqie 2.0.1-4
mate-desktop 1.26.0-1
Linux 6.1.5-arch2-1
```

The geeqie image viewer has a menu item 'copy path to clipboard'.

Is this 'clipboard' the global clipboard, so that I can, say, paste the path into an email.

If so then this is not working. My paste buffer is not affected by this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geeqie is using the primary selection, not the clipboard. Use middle-click to paste the path.